# JavaFX background colour not being set with CSS

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have recently started using JavaFX from a switch over from Swing but I have encountered a problem, basically the CSS from the Stylesheet that I have added isn't being added and just stays the same however from what I've read it should work.

Main file:

```
package com.callum.launch;

import com.callum.construct.Window;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Window.Create("Callum's Program", 980, 640, true);
        Window.launch(Window.class, args);
    }
}
```

Window File:

```
package com.callum.construct;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Window extends Application
{
    protected static String  WindowTitle;
    protected static int     WindowWidth;
    protected static int     WindowHeight;
    protected static boolean WindowResizable;

    public static void Create(String title, int width, int height, boolean resizable)
    {
        WindowTitle     = title;
        WindowWidth     = width;
        WindowHeight    = height;
        WindowResizable = resizable;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception 
    {
        Group root   = new Group();
        Scene window = new Scene(root, WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
        stage.setScene(window);

        stage.setTitle(WindowTitle);
        stage.setResizable(WindowResizable);
        stage.setMinWidth(WindowWidth);
        stage.setMinHeight(WindowHeight);

        window.getStylesheets().add("com/callum/construct/stylesheet.css");

        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Stylesheet:

```
.root
{
    -fx-background-color:#000;
}
```

The stylesheet is being found as I am not getting and error/warning in the console.

Comment: Looks fine to me.. tried simply changing the color?

Comment: Yeah and it still comes up with the default white background colour.

Comment: You're getting the stylesheet for your `Scene window` and not `Group root`, try getting the stylesheet for your `root` or simply change `.root` in your CSS file to `.window`

Comment: Still doesn't seem to affect anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Group` does not have a `-fx-background-color` property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#group): that property is defined in [`Region`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region). So you need your root element to be some subclass of `Region`, such as `Pane`:

```
    Pane root   = new Pane();
    Scene window = new Scene(root, WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 
  Window.class.getResource("stylesheet.css").toExternalForm()

Answer (score -3):

You are using "JavaFX Application" yes? Try "JavaFX FXML Application". It's easier to create GUI. 
https://devnoobs.browse.cloudforge.com/cgi-bin/fakturkafxml/fakturkaxml/src/fakturka/mainwindow/ ;)

Comment: Link-only answers are deprecated, on SO.