# Setting background color for BorderPane works in line but not within CSS file

Tags: java, css, javafx

So I have a border pane and I want to set it's background color with `-fx-background-color: black`. When I do this 'inline' like this:

```java
    borderPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");
```

it works fine, but if I instead add a class selector to it and try setting the color within the selector, like this:

```java
    borderPane.getStyleClass().add("env-pane");
```

and css like this:

```css
.env-pane {
  -fx-background-color: black;
}
```

No changes take place. I'm not sure if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708949/javafx-background-colour-not-being-set-with-css) is related. Looking at the Javafx css reference the pane class [has](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#pane) the `-fx-background-color` property.

If it helps, I added the style sheets to the scene and other components change based off of it fine.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Did you add the CSS to the class ?!

Answer (score -1):

I tried to re-create your problem but seems like it works for me. I'm using JDK 8 by the way.

Comment: I'm using the bellsoft jdk 15 which is bundled with javafx. I can post a reproducible example later today